# <a> tag is not open in another tab

Tags: magento2, link

Im trying to put a link using < a > tag inside a translate text. I got this using the next code

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getNoResultText() ? $block->getNoResultText() : __('Your search returned no results. Try searching in our <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="%1">Student Store</a>', $block->escapeUrl($this->getBaseUrl().'store/')), ['a']) ?>
```

I have no problem getting the link inside the text but for some reason the attribute target is not working

[image]

Is there something wrong in the code that im using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `escapeHtml` you have some additional restrictions

You can use only `id`, `class`, `href`, `title` and `style` HTML attributes. But you cannot use `style` attribute for `a` tag.

See `\Magento\Framework\Escaper`

Possible workarounds:

- Rewrite escaper with preference
- Add specific class to link like `external` and process it with JS

Comment: Thanks for answer and ok, I didnt know that. I put the <a> tag outside the translate text and the result was
<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getNoResultText() ? $block->getNoResultText() : __('Your search returned no results. Try searching in our')) ?> <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($this->getBaseUrl()); ?>store/">Student Store.</a>